# How to pass signInSuccessUrl dynamically to gitkit identity toolkit's widget

Tags: google-identity-toolkit

I am trying to pass the signInSuccessUrl parameter dynamically to the widget page as an URL parameter. Unfortunately without success.

According to the gitkit forum (https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-identity-toolkit/grF6C4CByEk/Dz4l2P-mTOwJ) this should work.

Am I missing something? Thank you.

That's what I tried:

1. The signin.html page showing the widget is configured like this:

JS Config:

```
var config = {
apiKey: '...',
idps: ["googleplus"], 
//signInSuccessUrl:NOT SPECIFIED CAUSE WE PASS IT VIA URL,
oobActionUrl: '//127.0.0.1:8888/gwt/servlet/gitkit/email',
siteName: 'SN',
};

window.google.identitytoolkit.start(...);
```

2. Open browser and show Javascript console of browser
3. Enter the widget page url in browser:
   http://127.0.0.1:8888/signin.html?signInSuccessUrl=127.0.0.1%3A8888%2Fgwt%2Fservlet%2Fgitkit%2Fsignedin%0A&o=dynamic
4. Continue with sign in...

This will not redirect to signInSuccessUrl but rather produce the error:

Uncaught Error: **Configuration signInSuccessUrl is required**.Si @ gitkit.js:217Ik @ gitkit.js:248(anonymous function) @ gitkit.js:257(anonymous function) @ gitkit.js:152(anonymous function) @ gitkit.js:213Fc @ gitkit.js:38h.dispatchEvent @ gitkit.js:36zi @ gitkit.js:210U.onReadyStateChangeEntryPoint_ @ gitkit.js:208U.onReadyStateChange_ @ gitkit.js:208

NOTE: if I set the signInSuccessUrl param in widget config, like: 
signInSuccessUrl:"//127.0.0.1:8888/gwt/servlet/gitkit/signedin?o=hardcoded",

It will work but NOT use the signInSuccessUrl provided in the URL but the hardcoded one, i.e. the 'o' param in this example will not be overriden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it did not work was related to using the open scheme in oobActionUrl
'//127.0.0.1:8888/gwt/servlet/gitkit/email'

When using 'http://127.0.0.1:8888/gwt/servlet/gitkit/email' it did work.

Answer (score 0):

the signInSuccessUrl in the widget configuration is a required field. You always have to provide it. The signInSuccessUrl parameter in the widget url if provided will override the config value. This makes sense since the signInSuccessUrl query parameter is optional and may not always be provided in the url. Try providing it in the config and then pass it in the url. It should work the way you want it to.

Comment: I had suspected that and tried it (see bottom part of question) but the URL was not overridden, I.e. the o param remained 'hardcoded'.